# How can I create a dynamic login button in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, forms-authentication, embedded-ruby

Anyone know how I can make a login button in Ruby on Rails for an application?

I assume the redirection will be something like:(I'm using current elements)

```
<%= link_to 'Log In', index_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
```

However, this will just create a button that redirects to the index, regardless if the "user" has filled in the required "Email" and "Password" fields. I assume I'll need a condition to check if the fields are filled and I assume a database table for accepted e-mails with the correct passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually several ways to handle authentication and user roles, I would suggest searching around for Devise to start with. after you understand how they are managed you might try yourself using DB relations or session hashes.

Have fun learning:

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And I will do so.